# Entity Framework Code First and Identity

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, code-first

I have a three layer project(DAL, Domain, MVC). I need to bound `AuthorEntity` from the DAL with `ApplicationUser`, which is in the MVC project.

They have a different `context(EfContext, ApplicationDbContext)`.

First, I created a `UserEntity` and tried to implement `IUser`, which has `string field Id (sting Id{get;})`, I got an error:

> "EntityType 'UserEntity' has no key defined.Define the key for this
>   EntityType"

I add attributes:

```
[Key]
[DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)]
```

It's not working. How to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Primary Key property must be readable and writable.

```
[Key]
[DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)]
public string Id{get;set;}
```